# Prevent deactivate of tab in browser by html, meta tags or javascript for a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Currently a new feature is rolled out by chrome and firefox as I have seen in the what's new screens.

The browser wants to deactivate tabs that are not in the front or active. So possibly also when the browser is not topmost, but I am not sure about that. Definitely if it is multitab it deactivates covered tabs.

We are developing a webpage for controlling and monitoring machines. Is it possible to instruct the browser to exclude this page from optimizing memory and deactivate the tab? So the user can switch the tabs to switch between different machine UIs but keep it up to date. Also covered tabs shall be able to receive push messages in cases the user needs to put the attention to the tab in question.

I searched google but maybe the feature is too new. I haven't found anything except that a user can deactivate it themselves in the browser settings. But I want to make it depending on certain pages.